# in a set of integer value, add some integer value, check the value is present or not if not then the insertion took place or not

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>    
#include<set>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

set<int> setofnumbers(set<int>& myset) {   //function for my random input
int s;
cout << "Enter the set of numbers(-1 to exit): ";
cin >> s;
while(s != -1){
    myset.insert(s);
    cin >> s;
    }
}
```

my problem in these section that I have to use the .find to check the numbers, there is error in the setofnumbers which I used as a function previously but I need that setofnumbers in here

```
void checkandinsert(int num){  //insert function to check integer present or not

set<int>::iterator it = setofnumbers.find(num); 
if( it != setofnumbers.end())
    cout << "NUmber " << num <<" inserted sucessfully";
else cout << "Number " << num << " was already present in the set";
}

int main(){    //main function
int x;
checkandinsert(2);
checkandinsert(4);
checkandinsert(6);
checkandinsert(76);
int size = setofnumbers(x)
cout << "Size of the set: " << size << endl;
for(set<int>::iterator i=size.begin(); i!=size.end(); i++)
    cout << *i << " ";
cout << endl;
return 0;
}

"my output suppose to look like"
Enter the set of numbers(-1 to exit): 1 2 3 4 5 6 11 -1
2 was already present in the set.
4 was already present in the set.
6 was already present in the set.
76 inserted successfully.
Size of the set: 8
1 2 3 4 5 6 11 76
```

Comment: You can simply use [`std::set::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert) for that.

Comment: you need to capture the return of `insert` and see if it actually inserted or not.

Comment: yeah my insertion was random in setofnumbers function but my problem in the second function : checkandinsert where I have to compare and check...any kind of help really appreciated

Comment: checkandinsert never tries to insert, therefore it doesn't do what it says it will do.  Also it is completely pointless because std::set already has that function.  Please read the documentation linked in the first comment.